# :nth-child and :nth-of-type not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have 3 buttons and for the second button I'm trying to add extra margin to it but for some reason nth-child and nth-of-type aren't altering the appearance at all. I'm guessing I just don't understand how they work so if someone could spread a lil love that would be great!

css code:

```
.ctabutton .viewbutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

.viewbutton:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 25px;

}
```

html code:

```
<div class="viewbutton"><a href="http://google.com">View</a></div>
```

Comment: Provide a fiddle to see exactly what's the problem, and for the difference between `nth-of-type` and `nth-child`, read this: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine... Perhaps there is something wrong with your `HTML`.

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ctabutton">
    <div class="viewbutton"><a href="http://google.com">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="viewbutton"><a href="http://google.com">View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="viewbutton"><a href="http://google.com">View</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ctabutton .viewbutton {
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.viewbutton:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Y2Uu/)**

It is changing the `margin-top` only on the second `div`

Answer (score 0):

nth-of-type works fine but you sad margin-top: 50px in (.ctabutton .viewbutton) selector than you overwrite it with viewbutton:nth-of-type(2) selector. If you want to add additional 25px you have to say 75px not 25px (50px+25px)

Comment: I fixed the problem by doing .ctabutton:nth-of-type(2) .viewbutton {
    margin-top: 25px;    Thanks for the suggestion!